# Problem with opencv2

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need to include the following files:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
```

but i always get this error.
Opencv2\opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

what shld i do?

will adding this line    solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10530/problem-with-opencv2/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-09**:
From @arebgun below: Are you using ROS Diamondback? How did you install it? I just created a small test packages that depends on opencv2 and roscpp packages these includes work fine.  Remember to try to post enough for others to reproduce your problem.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever you want to use code from packages other than the one you are developing in, you need to add dependency on that package to your manifest.xml (see [manifest documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest) for full description). And to answer your question adding `<depend package="opencv2"/>` to the manifest should solve the problem. Also your slashes are wrong, change all `\` to `/`:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-09**:
Great! Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-09**:
Thanks arebgun, problem solved.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-08**:
Try changing slashes in your includes (see updated answer).

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-08**:
trying to execute this code...

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-08**:
yup.. i wrote a code. it is on this link : http://answers.ros.org/question/1477/publishing-data-using-openni

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-08**:
Are you using ROS Diamondback? How did you install it? I just created a small test packages that depends on opencv2 and roscpp packages these includes work fine.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-08**:
same error... i tried a few times..

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-08**:
Hi thanks for replying.. I did add , but it still shows me this opencv2\opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simple answer to what's happening is that there is no opencv.hpp at that path. I admit I'm lazy and didn't try your code out, but try these two things:

1. Remove #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp". Recompile.
2. Do (1), then add #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp". Recompile.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-08**:
Cturtle has an older version of OpenCV, it might be that this particular header did not exist back then.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-08**:
Ah, ok. That's just a problem with cturtle then?

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-08**:
If he's on Diamondback with OpenCV 2.2 that header file is there.

**Comment by [brunohjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34988/brunohjs/) on 2018-05-06**:
Thanks! It worked!